# Laravel: Access data of relationship in Object with Blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, relationship, laravel-blade

I'm creating the following view in my controller:

```
$links = Link::with('cats')->get();

return View::make('home')
            ->with('links',$links);
```

This results in the following object:

```
{"id":1,"user_id":1,"cat_id":3,"link":"http:\/\/www.google.de","active":0,"description":"","created_at":"2014-07-16 19:46:23","updated_at":"2014-07-16 19:46:23",
"cats":[
{"id":1,"cat_name":"Design","created_at":"2014-07-16 00:00:00","updated_at":"2014-07-16 00:00:00","pivot":{"link_id":1,"cat_id":1}}
]},
```

So my cats are within the link object. But i can't access them.

I've tried this:

```
{{ $link->cats->cat_name }}
```

but i get this error:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$cat_name
```

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in the error message: you're trying to get the `$cat_name` property of a **collection**.

In short, the problem is this:  `$links->cats` is a collection of cat models. You want to get the name of a *specific instance* of the cat model, not the collection - the collection doesn't have a name.

Use something like this: `$links->cats[0]->cat_name` or iterate over the collection and get each name in turn.

Comment: Thank you very much! I used the $link->cats->first()->cat_name which is equivalent to $link['cats'][0]['cat_name']. That works. Your way works too i guees. :)